# Can't Start OpenGL Window

Tags: c++, opengl

I've got all the libraries properly installed as far as I can tell, but for some reason, `glfwWindowCreate` winds up returning `NULL`. I'm on a Dell XPS 15 at the moment, so I'm wondering if this has to do with the fact that I'm probably running this on the integrated graphics since it's not demanding enough for it to spin up the 1050ti. I'm brand new to OpenGL in general so I'm not certain that my code is properly written, so I'll post it here as well:

```
glewExperimental = true;
if (!glewInit())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW!\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

GLFWwindow* window;
window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize the window.");
    std::cin.ignore();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glewExperimental = true;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW!");
    return -1;
}
std::cin.ignore();
std::cin.ignore();
```

I've just updated my NVIDIA drivers to the latest update, so it's (probably) not that I hope. Unfortunately, I just can't seem to get it to open a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to initialize the [GLFW libraray](https://www.glfw.org/). GLFW has to be initialized by [`glfwInit`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#ga317aac130a235ab08c6db0834907d85e), before it is used.

The [GLEW libraray](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) has to be initialized after a valid OpenGL context has been created and become current. See [Initializing GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).

Change your code somehow like this, to solve your issue:

```
if ( glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE ) // intialize GLFW
{
    // error handling 
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

GLFWwindow* window;
window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// now the OpenGL context is valid and current

glewExperimental = true;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) // initialize GLEW
{
    // error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows, Optimus-enabled driver would look for an *exported* variable. That is application have to export it to be accessible to other modules. E.g:

```
extern "C" {
 _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

Value 1 would mean usage of high performance graphics. 0 or lack of any export would mean use  of low profile.

Now, if You're on MacOs or Linux or problem might be somewhere else.. MAc doesn't like Core profiles... On linux  you might forgot to disable  kernel modesetting and default opensource driver.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. I apologize if this is a stupid question, but where would I put this? On top of that, is this the actual section I need or just an example of what it might look like? Assuming that this is placed just above main (where I have my example in the original post), this unfortunately does not solve this issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about macOS. It supports Core Profiles just fine. You just have to specify that when you create the context.

Comment: @user1118321 OSX 10.7 and higher.. and few versions later OpenGL delared as deprecated, while in-between it didn't supported compatibility profile at all, while Core profile was  in strange state (there are low-level details that are different)